# Blog automatically redirects from .com to .in

Tags: blogger, redirect, disqus

I am new with blogger and all those stuff where i found that every-time my blog automatically redirects from ***xxxx.blogspot.com*** domain to ***xxxx.blogspot.in*** domain (thats because i am from India). i didn't use any meta tag which redirects my blog like,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/"/>
```

This automatically redirection leads to various other problems like disqus. Disqus works fine with my blog while it is in **.com** domain but it fails to load with **.in**. So is there any way to fix this ?? I want my blog to remain in **.com** domain irrespective of any country.

any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop country specific URL redirection by adding simple js script to your blog.

Just add the following code to above  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var blog = document.location.hostname;
var slug = document.location.pathname;
var ctld = blog.substr(blog.lastIndexOf("."));
if (ctld != ".com") {
var ncr = "http://" + blog.substr(0, blog.indexOf("."));
ncr += ".blogspot.com/ncr" + slug;
window.location.replace(ncr);
}
</script>
```

for more ccTLD redirection visit [dinetricks](http://dinetricks.blogspot.in/2014/04/disable-stop-country-specific-ccTLD-redirection.html).